# CSS tag live click not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid-asp.net

I have an anchor tag that is produced dynamically by a 3rd party library, JQGrid MVC.

It looks something like this:

```
<a id="xx" class="someClass" href="javascript:void(0)">Does Stuff</a>
```

I want to hook into it's click event as follows:

```
$(".someClass").on("click", function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/y2qfG/) to it.

This event is not firing, I believe because the 3rd party control that creates it has already got an event handler on it.

Is it at all possible to have my click event called and also then allow the 3rd party one to be called afterwards?

I'm using JQuery 1.7.2 and JQGrid 4.2.0

Comment: Is your jQuery inside a document ready call?

Comment: it is yes. I've tried outside as well, no dice.

Answer (score 1):

Try delegating the event

```
$("body").on("click",".someClass", function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

Looks like the event is not being attached because the anchor was being dynamically generated into your DOM. Delegating the event to the parent of the anchor should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks. "on" should work fine with dynamically added tags. I've tried your suggestion but it didn't work. The immediate parent is a td with a class EditButton so I tried: $("td.EditButton").on("click", ".someClass", function () {
        alert('hello');
    });

Comment: I think even the td is added dynamically right.. Select a parent that is static

Comment: Instead of href="javascript:void(0)"  try href="javascript:alert('hi')" and check if you see the alert

Comment: tried $(".someClass").attr("href", "javascript:alert('hi')"); in my doc ready but it hasn't updated the anchor tags